# BizTalk Schema generator in Visual Studio -- How to enable 'Well-Formed XML'?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 and BizTalk.
I create a new BizTalk-project in Visual Studio 2010.
I choose 'Add new item' and then 'New generated schema'.
Here I can choose 'Document type'.
I choose 'Well-Formed XML (Not loaded)' and choose an input file.

Now I get the message

> 'XFW to XSD schema generation module is not installed. Execute 'C:\Program files (X86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\SDK\Utilities\Schema Generator\InstallWFX.vbs to install the WFX to XSD schema generation module.

I try to execute that file and some text hastily appear on the console. I restart Visual Studio 2010, but it still doesn't work. Apparently the execution of the shell script didn't work. I try to restart the computer, but it still doesn't work.

Could anyone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 6):

If the script still does not seem to work, there are two dll files at the 'C:\Program files (X86)\Microsoft Biztalk Server 2010\SDK\Utilities\Schema Generator\' directory:

- Microsoft.BizTalk.WFXToXSDGenerator.dll
- Microsoft.BizTalk.DTDToXSDGenerator.dll

Close visual studio, manually copy dll files to **'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Developer Tools\Schema Editor Extensions'** folder and start visual studio again.

Comment: I have tried the above steps and it is working.Now I am facing

There were some errors generated during schema generation. Go to task list to view the errors.

Please help to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Try starting a console command prompt (run as administrator) and execute the script. If things go wrong, you will actually see the error message then.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Myfriend please follow below process to resolve your query

1. Go to
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\SDK\Utilities\Schema Generator`
2. Select the following files:

   - `Microsoft.BizTalk.DTDToXSDGenerator.dll`
   - `Microsoft.BizTalk.WFXToXSDGenerator.dll`
3. Copy them to
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\Developer Tools\Schema Editor Extensions`

[image: Screenshot of final folder structure]

Answer (score -1):

Restart Visual Studio after executing the scripts.